# Why jq list contructor and object constructor behaves differently for generators?

Tags: jq, cartesian-product

I want to get the Cartesian product of 2 lists, and tried following way:

```
echo [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] | jq '[.[0][],.[1][]]'
```

I expected to get [[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],....], but what I really get is [1,2,3,4,5,6]

But using the following 2 commands, I get the Cartesian product output,

```
echo [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] | jq '(.[0][] | tostring) + "," + (.[1][] | tostring)'
echo [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] | jq '{"x": .[0][], "y": .[1][]}'
```

My questions is: why does comma behave differently from "+"?  why does list constructor behave differently from object constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because thats how the [`,` operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Comma:,) in `jq` works. When two filters are separated by `,` then the same input will be fed into both and the  output value streams will be concatenated in order. In your case, both the filters return the corresponding array elements at indices 0 and 1 respectively and the result is collected into an array.

As for [Object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D), the manual makes it clear that,

> If one of the expressions produces multiple results, multiple dictionaries will be produced.

On an input

```json
{"user":"stedolan","titles":["JQ Primer", "More JQ"]}
```

the expression

```
{user, title: .titles[]}
```

produces two outputs, one for each value in the array `titles`

```json
{"user":"stedolan", "title": "JQ Primer"}
{"user":"stedolan", "title": "More JQ"}
```

So going back to your original attempts,

1. In the first case, each expression runs on the original input array separately and the results are just combined together into the bigger one
2. The third case falls into the case of object creation, when one of the expression produces multiple results. Since both your expressions generate multiple results, your result dictionary is formed as cartesian product of the two arrays
3. The second case is almost similar to 3), but the operations happen over string types i.e. each integer type converted to string before the cartesian product is generated. Note that this produces a result that is *neither* a list or a dictionary

You can still generate cartesian product on the arrays, when you do this

```
.[0][] as $x | .[1][] as $y | [$x,$y]
```

and put the whole thing into an array if you put the above filter inside `[..]` as

```
[.[0][] as $x | .[1][] as $y | [$x,$y]]
```

The reason this works, is because of [Variable binding operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier%7C...) with the syntax `expression as $variable`.

The expression `exp as $x | ...` means for each value of expression `exp`, run the rest of the pipeline with the entire original input, and with `$x` set to that value. Thus as functions as something of a `foreach` loop. So with our example, for each value in `$x` and each value in `$y`, we form the result `[$x, $y]`, which will be the resulting cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you so much so the detailed explanation. It is really helpful.